# covert the pairwise data to a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a similar question to the following poster:

[In Python: create a table to visualize pairwise data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831400/in-python-create-a-table-to-visualize-pairwise-data)

but my data missed lots of pairwise information. 
so if I use a similar implementation as in the poster. the program will report some fields is not involved in the fields name?

How I build a matrix will merge the unique field in both column 1 and column 2 and then print then out?

Thanks!

Comment: So what would be some sample input, and your expected output?

Comment: The sample input would be similar to the poster, ...i see x,y  x,z, x,c,,,,,,, but missing lots of pairs such as y,z etc.... the out put would be a similar matrix but covers all unique index showed in 1st and 2nd columns